# Duplicate key in Element table VueJS

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2, element-ui

I have the following code:

```html
      <el-table
        :data="getFormattedLocationTableData"
        style="width: 100%"
        :fit="true"
        rowKey="treeId"
      >
        <el-table-column
          prop="customerName"
          label="Клиент"
          width="400px"
        >
          <template slot-scope="scope">
            <img
              v-if="showDropdownArrow(scope.row.type)"
              :src="require(`@Svg/${scope.row.type}.svg`)"
              :alt="scope.row.type"
              class="icon"
            />
            <span class="item">
              {{ getRowName(scope.row) }}
            </span>
          </template>
        </el-table-column>
    </el-table>
```

When I am trying to run it I get the following error. Could you help, please?

```
 [Vue warn]: Duplicate keys detected: '1411'. This may cause an update
 error.
 
 found in
 
 ---> <ElTableBody>
        <ElTable> at packages/table/src/table.vue
          <LocationsTable> at src/components/tables/LocationsTable.vue
            <ControlLocationsPage> at src/pages/Control/ControlLocationsPage.vue
              <Layout> at src/layouts/layout.vue
                <Nuxt>
                  <DefaultLayout> at src/layouts/default.vue
                    <Root>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same key for different elements in the loop is causing this warning.
You can avoid this using different key for different v-for loops.
In your case, `row-key="treeId"` is getting duplicate values for "treeId".
Make sure to pass unique values to row-key.

```
`https://codepen.io/shwetas7/pen/PoJXZwN`
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Excuse me, what do you mean "duplicate values"? Do you mean that my treeId, for example, has same values in the same array?

Comment: @MikeS.  Yes  treeId are primary ids . they should be distinct. The same rule applies for 
v-for. The key props should be a unique value for each item in the Array.

Comment: Thanks a lot, hope it helps.